# How to use Extra Japanese keys with English layout

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have bought Hp omen whose keyboard is in Japanese layout but it got very small backspace button. since I am using English layout I was wondering can I use those extra keys which have no function in English layout and assign them backspace function?
Thanks